# Why JobListeners work in a local environment (IDE) but not in my production environment?

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.10.1 since java 8, when I register a JobListener in my pipeline I have observed that if I run it in a local environment (IDE), it works correctly, however when I deploy uberjar in my production environment, the listener does not work. Any idea what may be happening?

In this case, I am trying to detect that the job has finished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<String> texts = env.fromCollection(Stream.of("1", "2", "3").collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .map(new StringMap());
        texts.print();
        env.registerJobListener(new CustomJobListener());
        env.execute();
    }

public class CustomJobListener implements JobListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJobListener.class);
    @Override
    public void onJobSubmitted(@Nullable JobClient jobClient, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onJobExecuted(@Nullable JobExecutionResult jobExecutionResult, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {
        logger.info("Testing listener");
    }
}
```